# Laravel check if user belongs to certain company before login

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm developing an application to help companies manage its products.
First, the company should register itself to the app with an active admin user. The new registered company is not active by default.
I want to check if the user company active before logging in.

For example:
I want to register Nike to the app . the registered user is admin@nike.com
if I want to login with "admin@nike.com", it should not be possible till Nike company become active.

Database structure is like this:

### Company:

com_id
com_name
com_isActive

### User:

user_id
user_name
email
password
user_isAdmin
user_com_id

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: Well for one, you don't seem to have an active flag on your company table.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have relation in your User model. Something like

```
public function company()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}
```

In your LoginController (if you want it only there) or in some middleware you can check `request()->user()->company()->is_active` and do whatever you need. RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware is a variant if you don't want to make new middleware

Comment: My code looks like this: 
 <code>
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            request()->user()->bedrijf()->bedIsActive,
            $this->username() => 'required|exists:users,' . $this->username() . ',geb_isActive,1',
            'password' => 'required',
        ], [
            $this->username() . '.exists' => 'De gebruiker is niet active',
        ]);
    }
</code><br>
It throw an error **"Call to a member function bedrijf() on null"**
bedrijf refeers to Company in Dutch.

Comment: Probably you still don’t have user on request()->user(). Company check should come after login. Can’t do it before that

Answer (score 0):

1.First add column to the `company table` called `isActive` and `adminEmail`
2.Make a new Validation `Rule` called `CheckCompanyStatus` by this command

```
php artisan make:rule CheckCompanyStatus
```

3.Inside this rule put the following logic inside `passes()`

```
$data = \Company::where('adminEmail',$value)->first();
if($data->isActive == true) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

1. Go to LoginController and override the function `validateLogin()` and put this logic

   `protected function validateLogin(Request $request) 
    {
        $this->validate(['email'=>new \CheckCompany, 'password'=> 
         'required]);
    }`

Make sure to add adminEmail and isActive in your company registration form as well 
and use all the classes at the top 
Let me know if u have any errors